# Aggregate initialization with regular constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class dog
{
    public:
    int age;
    int bun;
};
```

Now this statement

```
dog d = {12,5}
```

would initialize `age` to 12 and `bun` to 5

Now if the class above has a parameter-less constructor the above statement initialization does not work. I would appreciate it if someone could explain why that happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax `dog d = { 12, 5 };` is *aggregate initialization* when the class `dog` is an aggregate. A user-provided constructor prevents a class from being an aggregate; cf. C++11 8.5.1/1:

> An *aggregate* is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no *brace-or-equal-initializers* for non-static data members (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

(I believe that the next revision of C++ will permit brace-or-equals initializers in aggregates.)

Comment: Thanks. That explained it. Marked as answer